# Downloading a region of a file using java

Tags: java, resume-download

I am trying to download a file using java. In order to provide maximum speed, I want to download the files as separate regions. I can use the  following code.

```
// Specify what portion of file to download.
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
```

But, with this I can start the download from the point X. What actually want is to download in-between regions separately. Say I have to download a file 1024 Bytes file, then I want to download the regions as 0-340 Bytes as section 1, 341 - 680 as section 2 and 681 - 1024 as the section 3.

How can I specify the range with interim values ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use the following code to download the region

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-340");
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=341-680");
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=681-1024");
```

This helped me in downloading the regions separately. :)